# What would be the result of the following htaccess code?

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

There's no way for me to test this htaccess code. For example my output URL is: `http://www.domain.com/index.php?mod=category`, what might be the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes `index.php` optional in URL which means if you go to:

```
http://www.domain.com/?mod=category
```

That should work fine just as well.

It is usually used by those frameworks which implement the [Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). With front controller design pattern, all requests of the web application are routed through `index.php`, so since it is needed always, one can use above htaccess rules to hide it altogether since it is obvious.

Comment: thanks. what if I wanted to redirect `http://www.domain.com/index.php?mod=category` to `http://www.domain.com/?mod=category`?

Comment: @jaysonatic: Use rules that you have in your question as I said in my answer :)

Comment: Will that code do the trick? Sorry I'm completely clueless with this htaccess. :P

Comment: @jaysonatic: Yes it does work for me. If you are clueless, it is whole big topic. If you have any other questions regarding it, you can come and ask here on SO :)